# What is the dimension of the "Julia set" generated by inverse iteration and why do I get numbers different from Hausdorff dimension

Tags: dynamical-systems, fractals, complex-dynamics

On the Julia set, the iterating the function $f:z\mapsto z^2+c$ generates a sequence of points  on the Julia set.  Because roundoff errors would be expected to cause the sequence to fall into an attractive cycle, I used inverse iteration $f_i:z\mapsto \pm (z-c)^{1/2}$, where a random number generator was used to pick the sign, to generate large numbers of elements for the (arbitrarily picked) value of $c = -1$.  The set looks like

[image: Julia set]

I generated large (1,000,000) sets this way and For a set of random reference points in the set, I calculated the number of points within various radii of each reference point.  The following graph is a log-log plot of the result:

[image: Log log plot]

Where the x axis is the radius and the y axis is the number of points within the radius.  The radii ranged from 0.0001 to 0.0512 in factor of 2 steps.  The slope of the line is about 0.855, suggesting a dimension less than 1, which is contrary to my intuition for this Julia set.

My guess is that I am studying a chaotic dynamic system, which results in sets that have a different dimension.  From a naive statistical point of view, if I have N >>1 points, and the number of points in a ball of radius r goes as $r^{0.855}$ then the number of balls needed to cover the set should go as $r^{-0.855}$, suggesting that the Hausdorff dimension is 0.855.

Comment: Your points do not have equal density along the curve. Thus you get the dimension shifted in direction of the dimension of the Cantor set. You can influence this somewhat by shifting the probability for the sign of the square root. In the end, the best measure is obtained by counting pixels that lie on or close to the curve.

Comment: Your intuition is right.  This Julia set is, in fact, connected.  So its topological dimension is (at least) $1$.  And therefore the Hausdorff dimension is at least $1$.  As Mark's answer  noted, the Hausdorff dimension is more like $1.367$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lutz comment on the density obtained via simple inverse iteration is certainly correct. There are, though, ways to modify the inverse iteration algorithm to obtain a more uniform distribution. You can find a description of these techniques with an implementation using Mathematica in [this paper](https://marksmath.org/scholarship/Julia.pdf). The main algorithm described in that paper is built into Mathematica as of version 10 and can be accessed via a command like

```
JuliaSetPlot[z^2 - 1, z, ColorFunction -> None, PlotStyle -> Black]
```

The modified inverse iteration algorithm is also implemented in [this web app](https://marksmath.org/visualization/julia_sets/), which I used to generate this image:

[image]

Performing box-counting on that image, I compute a fractal dimension of about 1.367.